# mysql and sql developer

Tags: mysql, sql

I found how to make sql developer connect to a mysql server and then I made a database. The problem I now have is that I cannot add my tables to it. Is it a syntax problem or am I doing something wrong? I have used (use database;) but now I see and error on some lines. Like in line 352, but it looks fine....

```
CREATE TABLE acctmanager

(amid VARCHAR2(4) PRIMARY KEY,

amfirst VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,

amlast VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,

amedate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,

region CHAR(2) NOT NULL);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's multiple syntax problems. You're using mssql syntax. There is no `varchar2` type in mysql, nor is `default sysdate` valid.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `varchar2` in `MySQL`

replace `varchar2` with `varchar`

Comment: I have use database; in line 1 but now its telling me...Error starting at line : 1 in command -
use sqlclass_books
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: No operations allowed after connection closed.